# How can I adjust the size of tabs to fit their content in an Google Maps info window

Tags: google-maps

Using Google Maps, I am trying to have an info window open with tabs in it, each tab showing a different city for the selected country. The problem is that the city names don't always fit into a tab so they make the design break. How can I change the dimensions of the tabs considering that I have to pass a string as tab label (not a node, which could be styled)?
Note that it is the tab label that doesn't fit, not the content.

Here is the code I use to add the tabs:

```
var tab1 = new GInfoWindowTab("string", node);
var tab2 = new GInfoWindowTab("string", node);
tabs.push(tab1);
tabs.push(tab2);
marker.openInfoWindowTabs(tabs);
```

where node is a valid DOM node, of course

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there isn't any good way to modify the styles of the tab labels.  Your best bet will probably be to check the length of your string, and shorten it if it's too long.  :(

**UPDATE:** You could try a third-party info window, but I don't know if any will support what you want to do with the tabs.  There are a couple options [here](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-utility-library-dev/) - try [ExtInfoWindow](http://gmaps-utility-library-dev.googlecode.com/svn/tags/extinfowindow/)

Comment: I guess I will simlpy add my own custom tabs within the content of the info window...
what about styling the info window itself? Can that be done? for example making it partly transparent...

Comment: The best you can really do is insert your own div into the info window and style that.  You could also use a third-party info window, but don't how they'll work with tabs.